# In Java, how do I find the proper path to open a txt file that's name is provided as a command line arguement?

Tags: java, file, text-files, filepath

I'm working on a program that is supposed to take two files as command line arguments, open the files, and read data from the files to make a data structure. 
So far, I have been able to make the structure using File() to open the files and Scanner to read the data. The problem is that I have been providing a specific path to the call for File like this

```
File f1 = new File("F:/MinSpan/resources/cities.txt");
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(f1);
```

I don't think this is going to work for the person who tries to run this program, because I have provided the path for where my specific txt files are located - they're on my flash drive (F) and in some folders. Is there a way I can program this to pass some kind of args[] value in for File() based on the cmd arguement the user has provided?

I have already tried just doing new File(args[2]) , and it can't find the file because there is no path.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, you should just use the `String` which is passed to you, test to see if it the file exists or not and take appropriate action - if the user doesn't pass a valid path/file reference, it's not your fault, you just need to deal with the possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is because, if you are passing in only two paths, args[2] wont return anything, because args[] starts at 0. So you'd want to use:

```
new File(args[0]);
new File(args[1]);
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense, yes. Sorry but I didn't explain the entire program: args[0] is taken up by a drive letter, so that's why I'm passing args[1] and args[2] for the file names.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for something like `java -jar program.jar FILE`, then have the program check for the `String` in `args[]` at index `0`.

Then, construct your file. Check if the file exists (in `java.io`, it's `File.exists()`) and return an error message to the user if it's wrong.